# Installing a specific version of mPDF

Tags: php, installation, mpdf

I am trying to install mPDF on my Centos server with PHP 7.0.33 and it continues to default to mPDF version 6.1. I need version 7 or 8. I tried manually uploading mPDF 8 from github but it creates a cryptographic fingerprint issue with composer.

Is there a way to force install version 8 or 7?

Comment: Don't use composer.

Comment: That’s still putting it in composer’s folder. Put it somewhere else, load it manually.

Comment: I'm using CodeIgniter 3, not sure where to put it, third_party folder I guess

Comment: is your cli PHP version really 7.0.33? what does php -v print out? I guess you cli is < 5.6

Comment: or there is a conflict of other libraries versions. what does `composer require mpdf/mpdf:^8.0` print out?

Comment: php -v gives PHP 7.0.33 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2018 12:52:03) ( NTS )

Comment: composer require mpdf/mpdf:^8.0: [InvalidArgumentException]
  Package mpdf/mpdf at version ^8.0 has a PHP requirement incompatible with your PHP version (5.4.16)

Comment: so WTH I have PHP 7 installed

Comment: which php
alias php='/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php'

Comment: Updating CLI PHP now....

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ultimately had to do. Since 'composer require' runs at the command line it detects the CLI version of PHP, which is different from what apache might be using. I updated my CLI PHP to 7.0 with the following script:

https://github.com/dfuentes87/change_phpcli.sh/blob/master/change_phpcli.sh

cd ~/

touch change_phpcli.sh

vim change_phpcli.sh

(I just pasted the code in since it is a small file)
save file then

chmod +x change_phpcli.sh

run the script ./change_phpcli.sh

and answer the question, I entered 7.0 for my version

Then run composer require mpdf/mpdf:^8.0

I also had to force my code to use a specific tmp folder for mPDF
for some reason using:

require_once APPPATH . '../vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => APPPATH . '../vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp/']);

and chown it to the user/group that run my web scripts:

chown myuser:psacln vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp/

Hope this helps, thanks for the pointers @Finwe